# Start Rails on boot for AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-on-rails, rc.local

i have a ubuntu EC2 instance and i want start my rails server at boot.
So i have a script:

## start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start Rails Server
cd ~/spree
rails server -d
```

and i have this in my rc.local:

## rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
sudo -u ubuntu -i ~/start.sh

exit 0
```

if i run "sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start", all work fine but at reboot the server not start...any suggestion?

Comment: `/bin/sh` I think doesn't recognise `~` path.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i have changed the ~ with my path, but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start Rails Server
cd /home/ubuntu/spree && rails server -d
```